# Checking whether user is logged in through memberful when clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, api, oauth-2.0, squarespace

I have a button on my website that should be sensitive to whether a user is logged in or not through memberful using the memberful api through oauth. I am not sure how to detect whether the user is logged in when clicking on the button. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.